# extension of eclipse XMLMultiPageEditorPart - trigger refresh of tree-view manually

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, treeview, eclipse-neon

I am working on an eclipse-plugin which makes use of a custom `XMLMultiPageEditor` by extending `XMLMultiPageEditorPart` and `XMLTableTreeView` by extending `XMLTableTreeViewer` the second one as well implements a `IResourceChangeListener`.

I provide this plugin in eclipse-mars and eclipse-neon, however the wired behavior only shows up in eclipse-neon.

The editor works fine so far, the only problem is, that the tree-view is completely blank when a related xml-document is opened with it:

[image: blank tree view]

I can even modify the document in the source-view and save it .. the tree-view stays blank.

The only events which bring the tree-view to life are:

- re-size the editor-window with the mouse
- open some other document and than switch back to the tab of the open xml-doc.

After that, the tree-view works like it should. If I now change the xml in the source-view, the tree-view is updated immediately.

Any ideas how I could trigger a refresh of the tree-view manually ?

Is this maybe a bug in eclipse-neon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem seems to be, that the x/y size of the TreeViewer in eclipse-neon is initialized with (0,0). Here a hack to fix that:

```
...
public class MyXMLTableTreeViewer extends XMLTableTreeViewer implements IResourceChangeListener{
....

public MyXMLTableTreeViewer(Composite parent, IEditorPart parentEditor)
{
   super(parent);
   ....
   Point size = getControl().getSize();
   size.x = 1000;
   getControl().setSize(size);
}
```

It seems to be sufficient to only set x to some value ... 10 already gives an image, but the "node" section than looks a bit pressed, so I picket 1000.

Even if it is just internal API, it looks like a bug for me. So if you are further interested, take a look to the [eclipse bugreport](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517360).

Answer (score 1):

Both `XMLMultiPageEditorPart` and `XMLTableTreeViewer` are in **internal** packages. This means that they are **not** part of the Eclipse APIs and can be changed by the Eclipse developers without warning (see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html)).

It may well be the case that something was changed between Eclipse Mars and Neon. You cannot rely on internal classes working the same between releases. It is not an Eclipse bug because you are not using official APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Was not my design-decision to implement it that way .. however I could change things & make use of the official API. Now it would be nice to know how the XML multi-page-editor / XML-table-tree-viewer is named in the official API.

Comment: There isn't an official API for this that I know of.